# How to determine if 3 points on a 3-D graph are collinear?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let the points $A, B$ and $C$ be $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2)$ and $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ respectively. How do I prove that the 3 points are collinear? What is the formula?

Answer (score 7):

From $A(x_1,y_1,z_1),B(x_2,y_2,z_2),C(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ we can get their position vectors.

$\vec{AB}=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$ and $\vec{AC}=(x_3-x_1,y_3-y_1,z_3-z_1)$.

Then $||\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}||=0\implies A,B,C$ collinear.

Comment: This is the best way of doing it - it provides an _algorithm_, rather than an existential condition.

Comment: okay, so this means that (1,1,1) (1,2,1) (1,1,3) are collinear but the problem system says I'm wrong can somebody pls explain this

Answer (score 1):

The three points $A,B,C$ are collinear if and only if there exists a real number $k$ such that
$$x_3-x_1=k(x_2-x_1)\ \ \text{and}\ \ y_3-y_1=k(y_2-y_1)\ \ \text{and}\ \ z_3-z_1=k(z_2-z_1).$$

Comment: Counterexample: $(0,0,0),(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1) \;$

Answer (score 1):

The formula is

\begin{equation*}
\text{rank} \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\
1 & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
1 & z_1 & z_2 &z_3
\end{array}
\right)\le 2
\end{equation*}

that is, the following three minors are zero

\begin{equation*}
 \left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_1 & x_2 \\
1 & y_1 & y_2 \\
1 & z_1 & z_2 
\end{array}
\right|
=
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_1 & x_3 \\
1 & y_1 & y_3 \\
1 & z_1 & z_3 
\end{array}
\right|=
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
1 & z_2 & z_3 
\end{array}
\right|=0
\end{equation*}
The rank $\le 2$ condition  also works for $3$ points in $n$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Find the three distances between the points.
Use Heron's formula (and these three distances) to find the area of the triangle.
If the area is positive, then the three points are not collinear. They form a triangle.
If the area is 0, then the three points are collinear.

Comment: This is _very_ prone to numeric errors - and if you break down Heron's formula, you'll find that it's zero iff either $a+b=c$ or $b+c=a$ or $c+a=b$; testing each of those (with appropriate tolerances) is much better than testing their product against zero, but the cross-product test is better still.

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between |AB|+|BC|=|AC| then A,B,C are collinear.

Comment: Please use [$\rm \LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189).

Comment: This only holds if $B$ lies between $A$ and $C$...

Comment: Do all 3 ways. If any are equal, then colinear.