# How to find if 3 non-collinear points exist in set of N 3D points?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947555/how-to-determine-if-3-points-on-a-3-d-graph-are-collinear) asked about test the collinearity of 3 points in 3D space, and the answer suggested a cross product of the pair of vectors connecting them. I am basically wondering how can one extend this solution to a set of N points?

The naive solution is to test points pairwise. However, computationally this seems slow. I feel like there must be a way to do this leveraging linear (in)dependence in an Nx3 matrix composed of the points. I also think there may be a solution using a covariance matrix of the data. However, I am stumped.

Ideally, I don't just want to test for collinearity, but rather find a metric that defines how close to collinear the points are (sort of an extension to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521171/collinearity-index-between-3-points-in-3d-space?rq=1)). My purpose is to find if there exists 3 non-collinear points in a set of N 3D points. *Is there an algorithm that can do this?*

If it helps, my use case is that I am determining a 3D affine transformation between point sets, and to recover the rotation I need my data to span the entire 3D space. I would like to test the points first before undertaking the transformation estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Pick two distinct points $a_1,a_2$ (for numerical stability, prefer them far apart). Find two vectors $v,w$ orthogonal to $a_2-a_1$ (e.g., let $v$ be the longest of $e_i\times(a_2-a_1)$ where the $e_i$ are the standard basis, and then let $w=v\times (a_2-a_1)$)  and compute $c_1=v\cdot a_1$, $c_2=w\cdot a_1$. then loop over all other points and check if $v\cdot a_i=c_1$ and $e\cdot a_i=c_2$ (or $\approx$ with suitably chosen error allowances)

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved more simply by doing the same thing but projecting onto the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix rather than using the elementary basis? (Maybe not more simply by hand, but with numerical tools it's simpler)